# Paint does not get added to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, repaint

So I have two classes, one is in charge of creating the JPanel and also overrides paint. The other contains the main and uses this other class. For the sake of ease, I've cut out what isn't involved in graphics. This first one does the JPanel and paint. The second is the main. I apologize for any poor structure or mess, I'm relatively new and I've just been throwing things in to see what works. The stuff in the paint is only a test, it isn't the primary goal.

```
public class PokerTable extends JPanel {

private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH * 3 / 4;
private static final String NAME = "Test";
private JFrame frame = new JFrame(NAME);

    public PokerTable() {

        //frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        //frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

This next one does more than call the PokerTable, but I've left the other parts out as they rely on other classes and just print to console.

```
public class Poker{

public static void main(String[]args) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    PokerTable pt = new PokerTable();

    pt.repaint();

}
```

Not that I necessarily expected it to work, I've changed the extension on PokerTable to Canvas and JFrame without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the panel to the frame, try with:

```
frame.add(this);
```

in PokerTable constructor

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked before but then I did a bunch of changes. I don't know how it worked before, but it works fine now it seems. I knew the problem would be far too simple and I was probably looking at it too hard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the panel to the frame, or the panel will never repaint.

```
frame.add(panel) or frame.add(this)
```

is what you need to call depending on where you do it.

Also, you should be overriding paintComponent, and never paint directly. that won't cause your code to fail, but it is bad practice.

Comment: I will keep paintComponent in mind. I had it initially but changed it as part of the throwing everything at the wall to see if it will stick. Now I must ask, is it also bad to be using JPanel in this particular situation? I will be using images and JButtons possibly, nothing is being drawn with g2d. The diffierences in swing and awt aren't set to me quite yet.